# Dynamic list with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to scripting and currently I'm doing some stuff with html, javascript and php. Im having issue with html where I want that when a user chooses a particular item from the first list the second list will be populated accordingly. however they are being empty

Done some research on the internet and other forums however issue still not solved even though I've changed some code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(s1,s2) {
        var s1 = document.getElementByID(slct1);
        var s2 = document.getElementByID(slct2);
        s2.innerHTML = "";

        if(s1.value == "Email"){
        var optionArray = ["Cannot Login|Cannot Login", "Cannot Sent Email|Cannot Sent Email"];

        }
            for(var option in optionArray){
            var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair [1];
            s2.options.add(newOption);
            }
}

</script>
</head>
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="Print">Print</option>
    <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
</select>
<hr />
Select your issue:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
```

if the user chooses email the options should be displayed

Comment: ...document.getElementByID(slct1);   ---> document.getElementById(s1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
function populate(param1,param2) {
     var s1 = document.getElementById(param1);
     var s2 = document.getElementById(param2);
     ...
```

and also mistake was `getElementByID`, but its actully `getElementById`

```js
function populate(param1,param2) {
        var s1 = document.getElementById(param1);
        var s2 = document.getElementById(param2);
        s2.innerHTML = "";

        if(s1.value == "Email"){
        var optionArray = ["Cannot Login|Cannot Login", "Cannot Sent Email|Cannot Sent Email"];

        }
            for(var option in optionArray){
            var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");
            newOption.value = pair[0];
            newOption.innerHTML = pair [1];
            s2.options.add(newOption);
            }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="Print">Print</option>
    <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
</select>
<hr />
Select your issue:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select></html>
```